# Execute batch jobs sequentially

Tags: sbatch

I have a batch job which looks like this

sbatch --wrap "perl test.pl file1 file2"

sbatch --wrap "perl test.pl file3 file4"

sbatch --wrap "perl test.pl file5 file6"

sbatch --wrap "perl test.pl file7 file8"

& the list goes on till

sbatch --wrap "perl test.pl file49 file50"

How can I  run individual jobs sequentially? 
Thanks,

Comment: I guess it depends on what a "job" is, but isn't that what your batch is doing?

Comment: 1-2-3-4 and on until 49-50 is already sequential. What can we help you with?

Comment: Actually, when I paste them on the command line in this format (or put them together in a file), they all run in parallel.

Comment: Did you happen to read the help for SBATCH? That is what it was designed to do.

Comment: I have never used sbatch but did a quick Google Search with your keywords and found this. https://chuckaknight.wordpress.com/2016/08/02/slurm-scheduling-so-they-run-sequentially/

Comment: @KenWhite, the problem is that once on the queue, they can all be started by the system at once and run simultaneously.

Comment: @Squashman Thanks. I first tried the answer posted by Poshi below and that worked perfectly.

Comment: @JTh, then why did you use the `batch-file` tag?  If you used Poshi's code below then your question has nothing to do with the `batch-file` tag.

Comment: @Squashman Sorry, that was a mistake. I had meant to write "batch job".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must make one script dependent on the finalization of the previous one:

```
JOBID=$(sbatch --wrap "perl test.pl file1 file2" | awk '{print $4}')
for N in {3..49..2}
do
    JOBID=$(sbatch -d afterok:$JOBID --wrap "perl test.pl file$N file$(($N+1))" | awk '{print $4}')
done
```

BTW, the `singleton` approach suggested in a comment is also a good approach, and frees you from the JobID management harrasement.

Comment: I think they might be running this on Windows considering the `batch-file` tag they used.  They may not have bash shell installed.

Comment: Well, at least he can grab the idea. How he implements the loop is completely up to him. Just putting all the commands one after the other will do. Or using the singleton approach, which will be even easier for this specific task.

Comment: @Poshi your solution worked perfectly. Thanks so much.

Comment: I know ;-) I do that kind of things on a daily basis. Now, accepting the answer would be a good thing :-)